# Wordpress submenu change URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url, redirect, filter

I want to change the url of my submenu item (which is all pages and subpages) depending if the page has a custom field with a specific name it will change the url in the submenu or not.

I have been trying to get this done, using redirection 301 works fine, but i don't like using redirections 301.

The redirection 301 that works looks like this:

```
global $post;
$field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirect', true);
if($field) wp_redirect(clean_url($field), 301);
```

it detects the "redirect" post field data name, and if it exits it redirects you to the given URL on the custom field.

, i have been trying using get_page_link() and filters but can't make it work.

Comment: create two menu, in header use your script change the menu accordingly instead of redirect.